# Нужен ли root доступ для снятия логов в приложении?

Tags: android, логирование

Я хочу организовать снятие логов падения приложения, и отправку на электронную почту. Пока вопрос стоит не в отправке на почту, а просто в снятии логов. Для того чтобы получить эти логи, я так понял нам нужно получить для приложения разрешение в манифесте оно выглядит так:

```
android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

уже на нескольких источниках я встречаю утверждение что мне нужно получить рут права, чтобы считать логи. Так ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения стек-трейса ошибки через `UncaughtExceptionHandler` не нужно никаких привелегий - ни рут, ни `android.permission.READ_LOGS`.

Если же Вы хотите читать системный лог через терминальную команду `"logcat"` - тогда да, привелегии нужны. По `READ_LOGS` без рута можно было читать лог на старых устройствах - до `Jelly Bean`. Лог своего приложения, если память не изменяет, можно читать без привелегий, но нет никакой гарантии, что устройство вообще их отдаст.